# What's the problem with differentiating $y = \sin(x^2)$ by applying the limit definition of a derivative directly?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was taking the derivative of $y = \sin(x^2)$. I know that we can solve it by applying chain rule, but i tried without any rules, just like a normal method. This is what i did:

$$\frac{\sin((x + h)^2) - \sin((x)^2)}{h}$$

Is this method correct? If not, then why? Because wherever I search for the derivative of $y = \sin(x^2)$, none did like this. And also I am not able to come to the proper answer which is $2x\cos(x^2)$ through that method.

Can somebody help me!

Comment: It's correct, as it is just the definition, but as you have noticed it is quite hard to get the result this way.  That's why other methods (like the Chain rule) tend to be preferred.

Comment: ohh got it, you can post this as an answer, i will accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't try hard enough. Just for curiosity's sake, here you go. Notice this follows the pattern of the usual proof of the derivative of $\sin$, using the addition formula for $\sin$.
First,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}&\frac{\sin((x+h)^2) - \sin(x^2)}h \\ &= \sin(x^2)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(2xh+h^2)-1}h + \cos(x^2)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(2hx+h^2)}h.
\end{align*}
Now, recall from your text that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}h = 1,$$
so we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(2xh+h^2)}h = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(2xh+h^2)}{2xh+h^2}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2xh+h^2}h = 1\cdot 2x.$$
Similarly, you should recall from your text that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(h)-1}h = 0,$$
and so the same approach will show that the first term goes to $0$. This gives
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin((x+h)^2) - \sin(x^2)}h = 2x\cos(x^2),$$
as you desired.

**COMMENT**: This is essentially how the chain rule is proved, by the way, if you don't worry about every last technicality.

Answer (score 3):

This is OK,
but the chain rule is easier.

Continue like this,
using $\sin(x) = x+O(x^3),
\cos(x) = 1-x^2/2+O(x^2)$
for small $x$:

$\begin{array}\\
\Delta_h(\sin(x^2))
&=\dfrac{\sin((x + h)^2) - \sin((x)^2)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin(x^2+2hx+h^2) - \sin(x^2)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin(x^2)\cos(2hx+h^2)+\cos(x^2)\sin(2hx+h^2) - \sin(x^2)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin(x^2)(\cos(2hx+h^2)-1)+\cos(x^2)\sin(2hx+h^2)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin(x^2)(\cos(2hx+h^2)-1)}{h}+\dfrac{\cos(x^2)\sin(2hx+h^2)}{h}\\
&\approx\dfrac{\sin(x^2)((1-(2hx+h^2)^2/2-1)}{h}+\dfrac{\cos(x^2)(2hx+O(h^2)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{-\sin(x^2)((2hx+h^2)^2/2}{h}+\dfrac{\cos(x^2)(2hx+O(h^2)}{h}\\
&=-\sin(x^2)(h(2x+h)^2/2+2x\cos(x^2)+O(h)\\
&\to 2x\cos(x^2)\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 3):

$\sin (x+h)^2 -\sin (x^2)=2\cos \big(\frac{ (x+h)^2+x^2}2 \big) \sin \big(\frac{ (x+h)^2-x^2}2 \big) $

$=2\cos \big(\frac{ (x+h)^2+x^2}2 \big) \sin \big(\frac{ h(h+2x)}2 \big) $

So

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin (x+h)^2 -\sin (x^2)} h$

$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac 1h 2\cos \big(\frac{ (x+h)^2+x^2}2 \big) \sin \big(\frac{ h(h+2x)}2 \big) $

$=2\cos(x^2)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{
sin \big(\frac{ h(h+2x)}2 \big)}{\frac{h(h+2x)}2}\frac{ (h+2x)}2$

$=2x\cos(x^2)$